How to remove duplicate character sequences within a string?
I have a column in a tibble that should always have an 8-character string as its value, for example ABCDEF12.
Unfortunately, I sometimes get values with a duplication of 2 characters in the string, like ABCDCDEF12.
The order of the duplicated characters is not fixed, so it can be ABABCDEF12, or ABCDEFEF12, etc.
Do you have any suggestions for reducing these strings to 8 characters by removing the duplicated sequence?
If we take the above examples as input, we should always end up with ABCDEF12 as output.
Another important thing to know is that I work on a computer that does not have Internet access, I have tidyverse at my disposal but I will not be able to install any additional packages.

I don't know if I can ask this request for comment here, but this submission is now closed because it's considered not focused enough by senior members. I've read the relevant guidelines and I don't see how this particular submission could be improved. I'm quite happy with the current suggestions below so it's okay if this submission remains closed, but I'd like to understand what is expected for future submissions.

I guess another reason for closure could be that it's a duplicate of any other R question around "how to remove duplicated characters from string". Also, the question lacks details and an attempt to solve the problem. Is the correct input always composed of unique characters, if it's incorrect, is it always 10 characters long, is the duplicated part always composed of 2 characters, if there is more than 1 dupe, which one to select?

Let's say your character vector is string:
string <- c("ABCDEF12", "ABCDCDEF12", "ABABCDEF12", "ABCDEFEF12")

Then we can use base R strsplit+unique+paste0 iterating using sapply:
> strsplit(string, "")|>
    sapply(\(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse = ""))
[1] "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12"


Using utf8ToInt()
We can take a similar but I suspect slightly faster approach by converting each string to an integer vector of utf-8 codepoints, taking its unique values, then reverting back to a character vector.
vapply(
    string,
    \(x) intToUtf8(unique(utf8ToInt(x))),
    character(1)
)

#   ABCDEF12 ABCDCDEF12 ABABCDEF12 ABCDEFEF12
# "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12"

In R unique() keeps the first occurrence of every element and maintains order.
Using regex
If your data is large, I imagine regex will be quicker than the above approach, as vectorised string operations are faster than creating and destroying lists of character vectors. If you want a regex solution you can port this JavaScript answer to R:
gsub("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "", string, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12"

The logic of this regex is:

Note though that this keeps the last occurrence of each character. This is fine if the repetition is guaranteed to be consecutive, as in the test cases. However, it may not be desirable if you have a string where the repeated character is on either side of another character. For example, with "ABCBD", I imagine you want "ABCD". The unique() approach will produce the desired result, but this regex will not.
x <- "ABCBD" 
gsub("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "", x, perl = TRUE) # Not "ABCD"
# [1] "ACBD" 

To resolve this, we can't just swap a lookbehind for a lookahead, because you can't have the backreference before the match. If you still want to use regex, one way around this is to use the same pattern but reverse the string before applying it, then reverse it after the substitution:
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(
    stri_reverse(x),
    "(.)(?=.*\\1)", ""
) |> stri_reverse()
# [1] "ABCD"

If you have the tidyverse installed, you'll also have stringi as stringr depends on it.
Data
Data from the answer by Jilber Urbina:
string <- c("ABCDEF12", "ABCDCDEF12", "ABABCDEF12", "ABCDEFEF12")


I have accepted @Jilber Urbina's reply, but thank you so much for this extremely detailed and well-written response. Indeed, as mentioned in the test cases I gave, the repetitions were guaranteed to be exclusively consecutive, but thank you as well for the suggested generalization.

This isn't a novel solution, but just a re-write of @Jilber Urbina using some tidyverse tools:
Keep first occurrence:
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

map_chr(str_split(string, ""), compose(str_flatten, unique))
[1] "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12" "ABCDEF12"

Keep last occurence:
map_chr(str_split(string, ""), compose(str_flatten, rev, unique, rev))

